# Как сверстать такую секцию через FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, css3

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #acacac;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dualblock img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.flex-element:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-element {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <img src="http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/nacionalnyy_park_kanada_britanskaya_kolumbiya_ozero_gory_derevya_dog_lake_14665_300x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть такая секция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ее сверстать с помощью FlexBox'a так, что бы потом можно было адаптировать?

Получилось только вот так(при адаптиве):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. флекс элементы заняли 100% ширину флекс контейнера. Добился с такого состояния при помощи медиа, задал при ширине `525px` и `flex-direction: column` :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тебе надо сюда добавить код, что бы получить ответ...  самодостаточный воспроизводимый привет...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ghb3ogd0/

Comment: @Air, ты уже второй раз пишешь "привет" вместо "пример", поэтому снова тебе Привет))

Comment: @DaemonHK ))) не замечал...  в следующий раз буду внимательней, это когда с трубы авто-замена, чтоб ее черти....

Comment: @Air, Зайдите на JSFiddle, там пример(уменьшите окно), единственное что нужно это сделать так что бы картинки стали посредине, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у меня вышел такой вариант

к `.flex-container` вместо `justify-content: center;` прописал `justify-content: flex-start;` чтоб блоки были с лева на право и для `.flex-container` по нижей 925px, вместо `flex-direction: column;` прописал `flex-direction: row;` и дал `flex-wrap:wrap;` чтоб блоки уложились в 2 уровня

Ниже

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #acacac;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-element img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-element:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .flex-element {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:75%;
  }
  .flex-element:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <img src="http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/nacionalnyy_park_kanada_britanskaya_kolumbiya_ozero_gory_derevya_dog_lake_14665_300x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А далее вы уже можете при адаптации писать ширину в % для .flex-element

Comment: Это не то что мне нужно, результат то не изменился. Нужно что бы блоки разместились по середине при 925px; и растянулись на 75% допустим.

Comment: добавил '.flex-element img{width:100%;}' чтоб картинка была на всю ширину блока код выше немного под правил

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду с этим разбираться.

Comment: бо как по мне лутше вместо column писать row с flex-wrap:wrap; тогда блоки уже будут укладаться не в одну линию а в несколько

Answer (score 2):

я не знаю твоих планов, в @media сам определишь правило, что бы было как хочешь

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #acacac;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dualblock img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.flex-element:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-element {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <img src="http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/nacionalnyy_park_kanada_britanskaya_kolumbiya_ozero_gory_derevya_dog_lake_14665_300x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="dualblock">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/5/19/small/478487195100977.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уже выше дали решение, спасибо :)

Comment: тогда прими ответ, не оставляй  без внимания человека..

Comment: Я не знал как это делается, принял уже :)